# Express 4.17 req body is empty

Tags: node.js, express, rest, body-parser

The `req.body` always is empty.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const userRoutes = require('./routes/user.routes');
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => console.log("app listening."));
```

routes/user.routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ requestBody: req.body });
});

module.exports = router;
```

client script:

```
fetch('/user', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ testData: "testData" }),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(responseData) {
        console.log(responseData);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
        }
    });
```

Result of fetch in console:

```
{requestBody: {}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that you install the latest express version locally by using this command:

```
npm i -S express
```

if the problem persists, try using another Browser

Comment: I tested by another browser and fixed problem. tnx haj ali

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body) for `req.body`

> By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

---

So you need to use a middleware to populate the `req.body`

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

router.use(bodyParser.json())

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ requestBody: req.body });
});
```

Comment: not sure why this was upvoted, OP is using `express.json()`, body-parser package is built in

Comment: I tried with both (`bodyParser.json()` and `express.json()`) , but not working